# Combine images to PDF pages with ImageMagick

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, png, imagick

I've created a multiple page PDF where I was supposed to add dynamic text to one of the pages (2nd of 3 pages). When I found out my shared host doesn't support PDF manipulation, I had to resort to using ImageMagick, convert each page to its own PNG file.

Adding text using ImageMagick is a dream, but I want to add the front page and back page. I need to combine `page1.png`, `page2.png` (with added text) and `page3.png` to `output.pdf` but I can't find the right code for doing it with PHP `Imagick()` class.

I thought I was doing the right when I used the `addImage()` function, but this wouldn't do it.

What I tried:

```
<?php

$combined = new Imagick();

$frontpage = new Imagick('png/frontpage.png');
$backpage = new Imagick('png/backpage.png');

$insidepage = new Imagick('png/inside.png');
$draw = new ImagickDraw();

$draw->setFillColor('black');

$draw->setFont('fonts/Georgia-Bold-Italic.ttf');
$draw->setFontSize(44);
$insidepage->annotateImage($draw, 2020, 268, 0, 'Text goes here');

$draw->setFont('fonts/Georgia-Italic.ttf');
$insidepage->annotateImage($draw, 2020, 987, 0, 'Text goes here');

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');

$combined->addImage( $frontpage );
$combined->addImage( $insidepage );
$combined->addImage( $backpage );

$combined->setImageFormat('pdf');

echo $combined;
```

Comment: What happens instead of it working?

Comment: PDF preview mode in Chrome, with no contents. I found out that I needed to use imagemagick to save to pdf and then read the contents of that file in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

While browsing for another problem I saw this old one which is incompletely answered. For the sake of completeness: The issue is not, that the file has to be written to file storage before displaying on the users browser, rather the usage of echo is causing the empty browser preview.

Use `echo $combined->getImageBlob();` instead of `echo $combined;`.